# Ways to get free and legal access to research papers as a researcher

Tags: publications, journals, publishers

I’ve discovered that website like ResearchGate offer the possibility to ask the paper editor to provide his paper for free. Many are collaborating.

Are there any other ways for researchers to obtain free access to papers?

Comment: Research library...

Comment: @keshlam: I don't have access to any research library I fear :( - but it would be nice to find any forum and ask people to download the paper and send to me.

Comment: @Revious That would break the licence that the person who downloaded the paper is bound by.

Comment: @MJeffryes: ok, this means it cannot be done publicly. But p2p and streaming are very spread realities and it's completely legal to say they exist. I wonder if there is something similar for research papers. This comment is legal, but if it's not welcome mod can delete it.

Comment: @Revious, that it can be done without being caught doesn't make it right.

Comment: The paper _editor_?  Don't you mean the _author_?

Comment: It is completely unclear how many papers at ResearchGate are available **legally**.  It is also completely unclear whether I should care.

Comment: @keshlam if you're talking about an offline research library, it's often not an efficient solution... too much time wasted transportation, finding the article, scanning it in case we need to keep a copy of it, etc.

Comment: @Revious - It's legal for you to *say* it exists, and it is illegal for someone to actually *do* what you are talking about. Your comment doesn't need to be deleted, but just be aware that you are advocating illegal activity.

Comment: @frankdemoncourt: I've done patent research by hand in a repository library, which is a roughly equivalent process of sifting haystacks for left-handed silver needles. It's certainly more work than an online search, but  the criteria stated were fee and legal, not easiest. And sometimes the paper search turns up connections by accident that an automated search wouldn't.

Comment: Whoever is paying for your research should provide you with access to a research library.  If you are donating your time and buying your own equipment for your research, that person is *you*.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I always use the following methods to get many inaccessible papers.

1. Open Google Scholar.
2. Search the title of the paper.
3. Click *see all versions* (you can see many places where the same paper is available)
4. Check one by one whether they are downloadable

Another method, I always use when I really need an inaccessible paper, is just to write an e-mail to the corresponding author to send that paper. My experience is that I have always received the paper in a return email.

Comment: Our university has better access than I do at home, too. You may be able to check if your institution has some sort of access (at home I can VPN onto campus). Depends on where OP is searching at.

Comment: You are right. It is really good if a institute has access to a large number of journals. But what about those journals to which the same institute has no access. So it is natural to face difficulties while downloading an essential paper from such journals. That is why I have mentioned inaccessible paper...

Comment: The other thing you can do is go through a university library -- try to get yourself some sort of position or student status (could be as an unmatriculated student, could be an online course).

Comment: @Kayan - Sorry, I only just refreshed the page and saw your comment.  The solution in that case is *Interlibrary Loan*.

Comment: Yes @aparente001 . That is also a good way. I had also that experience during my PhD. I don't know about your institute, but my institute was taking time up to a week.

Comment: It will be nice to see some screenshots here

Comment: I have also done this. If I recall correctly, I have received every paper I asked for.

Answer (score 20):

It turns out that a related survey was posted last year in [this PLOS blog post on how paleontologists access the (non-open access) literature](http://blogs.plos.org/paleo/2014/09/18/paleontologists-access-non-open-access-literature/):

[image]

[image]

> I put together an informal, non-scientific survey. The survey asked
>   questions about how people access the literature, the kinds of
>   journals they can access most easily, and basic demographics. I
>   advertised the survey via Twitter and Facebook. I wouldn’t count it as
>   a scientific sample by any means, but I do feel that I got reasonably
>   good coverage of various types of paleontologists at various types of
>   institutions (as well as non-paleontologists who follow the
>   literature). 115 individuals responded, during the course of about a
>   week.

Note that it doesn't indicate the legality.

FYI: [Bulk download Sci-Hub papers](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7084/1652)

Answer (score 14):

The website mentioned [here](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2016/02/16/thoughts-on-sci-hub) is obviously and blatantly illegal, but gives access to almost all journals ever published. It's very easy to use and more complete than our direct subscriptions. I might almost use it for stuff I have legal but slow access to.

Use or do not use depending on your views on the "illegal" consumption of research.

Comment: As the "illegal" consumption of research increases, this may hurt the editors, the publishers, and even the researchers themselves. ❧ I would downvote you if I had enough reputation points.

Comment: Let's be a bit realistic here: maybe the purchasing of individual articles accounts for 1% of the publisher's revenue. How is that going to hurt me as a researcher? It's not like I'm getting paid for reviewing or editing anyway.

Comment: A) 1%? Citation needed. B) Researchers depend upon publishers. When publishers get hurt, so do researchers, indirectly.

Comment: A) That's why I write maybe. Maybe it's more, maybe it's less. Either way, not a lot. B) I don't depend on publishers, publishers depend on me. When all the closed access only publishers disappear, we still have all the open access guys left, as well as things like Arxiv and whatever will take the place of Nature. Don't forget that a lot of Journals are not published by companies like Elsevier, but by associations or societies that could run on other sources of income.

Answer (score 7):

Ask your public library (maybe not a local branch, but a large city's one). In some places, libraries are able to help citizens access journals. Another option might be national libraries - eg the British Library.