# Are there any known Universities that refuse to pay for paywall access to academic journals?

Tags: journals, fees, paywall

Are there any known Universities that refuse to pay for paywall access (for moral, intellectual, inability to pay, or other reasons) to academic journal articles?

Comment: Sci-Hub and LibGen, depending on your point of view, occupy at best a copyright gray area and at worst are outright illegal. I doubt that any universities would actually _officially advocate_ for their use at this time. (Of course, _de facto_ the faculty and students will have to find alternative venues to access the journal articles if the subscription is cut off.) It would therefore be perhaps better to remove the references to SciHub and LibGen specifically, and instead ask about which universities have refused to pay for journal access, period.

Comment: There are certainly many universities that have canceled large numbers of journal subscriptions and left their faculty in the unenviable position of having to use services like this or buy access directly from publishers.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Why is using services like this unenviable? I find it convenient.

Comment: @WillieWong changed the wording of my question based on your comment. I was careful not to state that they were aware of any illegal activity. Downloading and sharing of copyrighted content (which I did not mention) may be treated differently (at least in some countries) than just viewing or reading it online.

Comment: The material about Sci Hub and LibGen is argumentative and out of place in this question.

Comment: Based on the feedback I received I have edited out a my mention of Sci Hub and LibGen and marked the answer to the first part of my question by  @FranckDernoncourt below as correct

Comment: @BenCrowell It indicates that there exist free alternatives, so I think it's appropriate to mention them (or any other similarly convenient services, no preference).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I will draft a second question regarding knowledge of University use of those resources, without combining it with my first question which you already answered

Comment: @MagnusGustafson Sounds good (and sounds like the question that would earn me downvotes), thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No University has [enough funding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/29923/452) to spend on subscription fees for all existing paywalled research articles (e.g., [Harvard University says it can't afford journal publishers' prices](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/apr/24/harvard-university-journal-publishers-prices)). As a result, some of their faculty and student resort to free alternatives SciHub/LibGen/emailing colleagues/[etc](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/51940/452).

Many universities located in developing countries [cannot afford paying for paywalls](http://ent.arp.harvard.edu/AfricaHigherEducation/Online.html).

If you need a particular University name, here are some:

[University of Sierra Leone](http://www.economist.com/news/middle-east-and-africa/21696673-sierra-leones-university-system-collapsing-trials-running-universities):

> When he needs new books to teach one of his courses, Professor Ibrahim Abdullah orders at least two from abroad: one for himself, one to give to the university library. If he needs scholarly articles, he writes to his friends overseas and asks them to send copies, since the university cannot afford journal subscriptions.

All public universities, research institutes and state agencies in [Peru](http://rpp.pe/ciencia/mas-ciencia/cientificos-ya-no-pueden-acceder-a-crucial-banco-de-datos-por-falta-de-dinero-noticia-1016735) (translated by Google):

> Bad news for research and technological innovation come from Peru. The
>   National Council for Science, Technology and Technological Innovation
>   (Concytec), a government agency, will no longer offer free access to
>   the ScienceDirect and Scorpus databases by the end of the year. The
>   lack of funding from the central government has been the cause of the
>   closure of these platforms for Peruvians.
>
> Access had been enabled for public universities, research institutes
>   and state agencies. ScienceDirect (Freedom Collection) gathers more
>   than 1,800 titles in full text scientific journals in 24 thematic
>   areas and Scopus meets "relevant sources for basic research, applied
>   research and technological innovation and is a tool for bibliometric
>   studies" according to the portal Concytec .
>
> Access was open since 2014 and during that time 3.7 million full-text
>   documents were downloaded. The downloads, according to Concytec, would
>   have cost US $ 131 million if they had been isolated. While
>   subscribing to these services for three years cost the agency only US
>   $ 10 million.

A few other places:

- [Dutch universities start their Elsevier boycott plan](https://redd.it/3bwp2q)
- [Germany-wide consortium of research libraries announce boycott of Elsevier journals over open access](https://redd.it/5inrwd)
- [Taiwan Tech to Discontinue Subscription to Elsevier ScienceDirect Starting 2017](http://library.ntust.edu.tw/files/14-1025-58346,r1-1.php?Lang=en)

---

Some [interesting](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/05/survey-most-give-thumbs-pirated-papers) [maps](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/04/whos-downloading-pirated-papers-everyone) showing the location of Sci-Hub users (at least the location of the machine that makes the final request):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kinda-relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1138/

Comment: @Azor-Ahai :) Good point, I wish plots were normalized by the population. But at least it reflects the newspaper article's title "Who's downloading pirated papers? Everyone"

Comment: Yeah, and you can see the Middle East and India is over represented.

Comment: The city data at the end is probably an artifact of geolocation as applied to automated scripts. Requests from Amazon Web Services machines will often come back geolocated to Ashburn, while requests from Fremont could be from one of Linode's more popular cloud hosting locations. Those hotspots could simply represent one or more people running a script to download large numbers of papers rather than large numbers of users in these locations using the site.

Comment: @ZachLipton People who need a dump of Sci-Hub/libgen would rather use the torrent files created for that purpose, and therefore shouldn't appear on the map as it only shows HTTP requests.  ([Bulk download Sci-Hub papers](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/7084/1652))

Comment: FWIW, there's a [population-adjusted map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) on Wikipedia (scroll down a bit on the right). Even there, it's somewhat misleading, because the percent of the population likely to be interested in academic journal articles (e.g. students, researchers, medical professionals, etc...) will vary greatly between countries. Sci-Hub may be extremely important to the vast majority of a country's grad students and researchers, but still underused by the broader population, especially where there exists greater educational inequality or even literacy.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Perhaps, and maybe some of that traffic is people running proxies through cloud hosting services and accessing it through HTTP. And not everyone uses the "best" method of access even when it is available. I don't have the one true explanation, but when you see a ton of network activity from a network hub like Ashburn, it usually doesn't mean lots of Ashburn residents are actually responsible.

Comment: @ZachLipton I agree.

Comment: Another reason is that areas with large academic populations also have large not-quite-academic populations (high-tech businesses, sceince writers, policy people, those trying to get back into academia...)  These people may well lack journal access but want it occasionally.

Answer (score 6):

This is not about a university, but I guess it also fits the bill:

The german "Hochschul-Rektoren-Konferenz" (German's Rectors Conference) has lauched "Projekt DEAL" where many (all?) German universities jointly negotiate with Elsevier about prices. Since the negotiations did not went well for the universities, **the over 60 German universities and libraries canceled their subscription to all their Elsevier packages to the next possible date**. My university has no subscription to any Elsevier journal starting 01.01.2017. It is currently analyzed what actions shall be taken with other publishers.

Read some background:

- [Official project website](https://www.projekt-deal.de/) (in German)
- [An article on ip-watch](http://www.ip-watch.org/2016/12/16/no-deal-german-universities-prepare-cut-off-elsevier-journals/)
- [News from Göttingen's university library](https://www.sub.uni-goettingen.de/en/news/details/voraussichtlich-keine-volltexte-von-zeitschriften-des-elsevier-verlags-ab-dem-112017/)

Comment: Apparently [Peru and Taiwan](http://www.nature.com/news/scientists-in-germany-peru-and-taiwan-to-lose-access-to-elsevier-journals-1.21223) are in a similar situation.

Answer (score -3):

Universities in the US do not refuse paywall access to journals for moral or intellectual reasons.  However, budget limitations may mean that subscriptions that are deemed less important may be canceled.

Comment: Part of the motivation behind the budget allocation choices is moral and intellectual. E.g., https://www.theguardian.com/science/2012/apr/24/harvard-university-journal-publishers-prices : "There's always been a problem with this being seen as a library budget issue. The memo from Harvard makes clear that it's bigger than that. It's at the heart of education and research. If you can't get access to the literature, it hurts research."